# Interacting with the web browser/handling redirects

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate web browser interactions. I've already got the login down, however on the page I'm attempting to work with, there is a redirect on a successful login - as far as I'm aware, the `webbrowser` module cannot handle redirects, so I've had to use `webbrowser.open()` to open the redirect links in the browser. My question is:
**Can the webbrowser module handle redirects? If not, is there a module that interacts with my browser to get a URL from it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the Selenium web driver for [Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). It can handle redirects. For many operations I've found it to be a lot slower than webbrowser, but anything you can do in an actual browser can be automated with Selenium.

Comment: I've been using `twill` for the logins and emulation of browser before opening it via `webbrowser` - do you know if selenium works well with twill/can completely replace it? I'm using twill's `agent`, `formvalue`, and `submit` to get past non-php-based login prompts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `twill` but have had a lot of success with form submission authentication using `Selenium`, including javascript generated login dialogs. I have had some issues using IE and ActiveDirectory authentication so that Selenium can't emulate the login, but other than that it's been able to GET/POST anything you can see on the browser.